Child Marriage as per Sunni and Shia Muslims, Is there any difference of opinion or not
As Ayatollah Khomeini says, it is not permissible to have intercourse before the age of nine, whether in nikah (permanent marriage) or temporary marriage. However, it is stated that all other pleasures like as amorous touch, hugging, and thighing are permitted even with a breastfeeding child.
What is the ruling regarding this issue in Sunni Muslim because I didn't find anything like this in Sunni Scholars books.

The answer to the linked duplicate covers the matter of intimacy other than intercourse.
